# Django Choice list Form between objects created with model class

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

i have a following class in `models.py`

```
   class Project(models.Model):
        project_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
        project_headers = models.TextField(unique=True) 
        projects_urls = models.TextField()
        project_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        project_results = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.project_name
```

And let's suppose i have created a 2 Projects objects with above class with following `project_name`.

1. google.com
2. facebook.com

---

I want to create a form where i can add `Django Choices list` as `project_name` objects to update their fields such as `project_urls`etc, based on `project_name` selected by User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this post: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html

It shows you how to achieve that using javascript. I have done this, and it works great.